# How to make a power method without for loops or recursion?

Tags: java

I'm thinking of a method that calculates the power (base 10 only) of an integer which will be passed as an argument but without using for loops or recursion:

here's the method in it's simplest form using forr loop:

```
 static long power(int val) {
    long y = 10l;

    if (val == 1) {
        return y;
    } else {
        for (int x = 0; x < val - 1; x++) {
            y *= 10;

        }
        return y;

    }
}
```

Comment: And why would you want to avoid loops and recursion?

Comment: using the built in method is out of scope :)

Comment: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/06/creating-java-me-math-pow-method.html Since you are only looking for integral powers of 10, an array is probably your best bet.

Comment: How about using `System.exec(...)` to run the `dc` command?  :-)

Comment: Since the most efficient way to do it without lookup involves a loop, I really wonder what kind of travesty this solution will end up to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `Math.pow`.

Assuming you don't want to do that, you could use a lookup table. There is only a small finite number of results that fit into a long. Something like this would work:

```
static final long[] results = { 1L, 10L, 100L, /* etc... */ };

static long power(int val) {
    return results[val];
}
```

Comment: I know the built in method well, but i want to do implementation on my own

Comment: @Eslam, and you think the bilt-in method doesn't use a loop?

Comment: actually it does, and iam the one who will do it without looping or recursion :)

Comment: @Eslam, no, not you, whoever answers this will

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to do that, but obviously, this would work:

(warning: as ugly as you want it)

1. convert the number to a string (using base-b representation, b=10)
2. append zeroes
3. convert the string to a number and return the result

Of course, this only *hides* loops

Comment: It hides loops only if you find a method which appends the right number of zeroes for you :-)

Comment: @JBNizet `"0000000000000000".substring(0,power)` comes to mind.

Comment: touché. Then all hope is lost, and we need to find a library that implements `pow`.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way using Strings. Something like...

```
String zeros = new String(new char[val]).replace('\0', '0');
String init = "1";
String out = init.concat(zeros);
return Long.valueof(out);
```

But i think replace will also use a loop inside. Maybe Array.fill doesn't (so you can try with char[])